# There was a problem using openstack4j for domain level authentication

Tags: java, openstack

Now using the `openstack4j` development package to develop our OpenStack application, we need to log in to OpenStack as admin, authentication at the **Domain** level, failed.
Now the user `admin` is in the project `admin` and is in the `admin` role.
However, when I developed with Java using a server under the LAN, I got an error. The code looks like this:

```java
    @Test
    public void list_projects(){
        OSClient.OSClientV3 os = OSFactory.builderV3()
                .endpoint("http://10.2.10.1:5000/v3")
                .credentials("admin","openstack2023", Identifier.byId("default"))
                .scopeToDomain(Identifier.byId("default"))
                .authenticate();
 
        System.out.println(os.identity().projects().list());
 
    }
```

There is nothing wrong with `http://10.2.10.1:5000/v3`. I can actually access the Dashboard using the Dashboard. Besides, the user name and password are also guaranteed to be correct. Domain information is as follows:

```bash
[root@openstack ~(keystone_admin)]# openstack domain list 
+----------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| ID                               | Name    | Enabled | Description        |
+----------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 1397d0590ccc481385442a73aadddc1d | heat    | True    |                    |
| default                          | Default | True    | The default domain |
+----------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+
[root@openstack ~(keystone_admin)]#
```

Code error content:

```
AuthenticationException{message=Unauthorized
, status=401}
    at org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExceptionHandler.mapException(HttpExceptionHandler.java:36)
    at org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExceptionHandler.mapException(HttpExceptionHandler.java:23)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSAuthenticator.authenticateV3(OSAuthenticator.java:191)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.internal.OSAuthenticator.invoke(OSAuthenticator.java:74)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.client.OSClientBuilder$ClientV3.authenticate(OSClientBuilder.java:172)
    at org.openstack4j.openstack.client.OSClientBuilder$ClientV3.authenticate(OSClientBuilder.java:129)
    at cloud.computer.backend.LowLevelAPITest.list_projects(LowLevelAPITest.java:37)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
```

Therefore, we hope that with the correct user name and password, we can still log in to OpenStack using `openstack4j` for domain-scoped authentication.
Thank you for your time and any help would be appreciated.